# Create directory with docker compose for elastic search and map it to the one on server

Tags: java, docker, elasticsearch, docker-compose

I have the following docker compose file for starting elastic search with kibana:

```
version: "3.5"
services:
 es-master:
  container_name: es-master
  image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.8.1
  hostname: es-master
  restart: always
  ports:
   - 9201:9201
   - 9301:9301
  environment:
     - ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS=http://es-master:9201
     - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms4g -Xmx4g"
     - bootstrap.memory_lock=true 
  ulimits:
     memlock:
       soft: -1
       hard: -1
  networks:
   - es-net

  volumes:
      - /data/es/config/config.yml:/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml
      - /data/es/data:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
      - /data/es/logs:/usr/share/elasticsearch/logs
      - /data/es/plugins:/usr/share/elasticsearch/plugins
      - /data/es/kibana/data:/usr/share/kibana/data
    kibana:
   container_name: kibana-container
   image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:7.8.1
   ports:
     - "5601:5601"
   environment:
      - ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS=http://es-master:9201
      - path.repo=/nfs_es/back_up
     
   ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
   volumes:
     - /data/es/kibana/data:/usr/share/kibana/data
   depends_on:
     - es-master
   networks:
    - es-net
networks:
  es-net:
    name: es-net
```

Basically I need to create a directory `/nfs_es/back_up/` on the **container** before elastic search starts up and map it to the directory `/nfs_es/back_up/` which I have already created on the current server. Can this be achievable with docker compose?

Comment: It seems like adding another `volumes:` line like the ones you already have should do that: Docker will create both the host and container directories if either doesn't exist.  Have you tried it?  What happens?

Comment: I ve tried  it, it create both if not exist